# Rosdep update problems

Tags: ros, installation, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I just set up a fresh Fuerte Installation on Precise and tried to install rosdep using the deb-packages. I successfully ran:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
sudo rosdep init
```

but

```
rosdep update
```

returns:

```
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an internal error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d'
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 111, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 230, in _rosdep_main
    return _no_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 238, in _no_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 341, in command_update
    filelist = [f for f in os.listdir(sources_list_dir) if f.endswith('.list')]
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d'
```

Seems like rosdep is trying to write somewhere it has no permissions. It works when I do:

```
sudo rosdep update
```

But trying to use rosdep, it again tells, it is not initialized:

```
rosdep install libmove3d move3d_studio

ERROR: your rosdep installation has not been initialized yet.  Please run:
        
    sudo rosdep init
    rosdep update
```

I don't think there is something wrong with my setup, I just installed ROS Fuerte and rosws fresh, but still it seems to be a problem with my permissions... any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45993/rosdep-update-problems/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just purged and installed again, same issue. My permissions are missing a read-permisson for others:

```
sudo ls -la /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
total 12
drwxr-xr-- 2 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:22 .
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Oct 16 14:08 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root root  557 Oct 16 14:22 20-default.list
```

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-10-17**:
Manually setting execution-permissions for others in /etc/ros/rosdep solved it for the moment, why have the permissions been set this way? Is there something wrong in the installation procedure?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-10-17**:
Unless others confirm this bug, I'd say you had bad luck, e.g. those directories existed already, although I don't know what could have set them up..

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-10-17**:
Yes you're right, I will close this question for now and let's hope it was just a weird coincidence with my configuration...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried purging rosdep and installing it again?

Could you paste the permissions from that directory an its files on your system? Maybe they are really not listable resp. readable for everyone.

This is how it looks on mine:

```
$ ll /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-03-16 11:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2012-03-16 11:41 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  409 2012-03-16 11:41 20-default.list
```

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-10-17**:
I just purged and installed again, same issue. My permissions are missing a read-permisson for others:

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FWIW, I had this same problem, and I was able to fix it using apt-get purge, then doing

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.ros/rosdep
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/ros/rosdep
```

Followed by a reinstall of python-rosdep using apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [dasid](https://answers.ros.org/users/3500/dasid/) with karma: 1 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-08**:
I had the same problem as michikarg, but your solution worked brilliantly for me. Just a note for others looking at this: don't forget to "sudo rosdep init" after reinstalling through apt-get! Many thanks!

**Comment by [RayR](https://answers.ros.org/users/4566/rayr/) on 2013-03-29**:
I confirm having the same problem and it being solved as mentioned by dasid.

**Comment by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on 2014-01-17**:
It works perfectly! I met the same issue and this is the correct solution:) I like it so much!